# Union of two boolean Rows with the same tag

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I Have a select statement that returns a array of elements for each tag:

```
|TAG  | Bool1 | Bool2 | Bool3 |
|-----------------------------|
|tag1 |  0    |   1   |  0    |
|tag1 |  1    |   1   |  0    |
-------------------------------
```

I want the result to be the union of the two rows  with OR statement:

```
_______________________________
|TAG  | Bool1 | Bool2 | Bool3 |
|-----------------------------|
|tag1 |  1    |   1   |  0    |
-------------------------------
```

Comment: Why does Bool2=0 if the same Bool1=1?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
SELECT TAG,
    CAST(MAX(CAST(Bool1 as int)) as bit) as Bool1,
    CAST(MAX(CAST(Bool2 as int)) as bit) as Bool2,
    CAST(MAX(CAST(Bool3 as int)) as bit) as Bool3
from Table group by TAG
```

Would seem to fit the bill, since if even a single row has a `1` value, that will overcome all of the `0`s in other rows.

Comment: Instead of casting to int, you can also just add 0 to bit to make it int - MAX(Bool1+0)

Comment: it worked but the result is turning to be a nullable bit which is not the case!

Comment: If this is for a view, and you're complaining about the derived type being marked as nullable, wrap the appropriate expression in an `ISNULL()` expression - something like `CAST(ISNULL(MAX(CAST(Bool1 as int)),0) as bit)`.

Comment: Actually it worked that way : ISNULL(CAST(MAX(CAST(Bool1 as int)) as bit),0), Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Be careful, `MAX` operator doesn't work with `BIT` fields. You must `CAST` your field in case its type is not `INT` to use the solution proposed by @Damien_The_Unbeliever

**Append**: *I assume that a field with a simple 1/0 value could be a bit*.

Comment: yes it is a bit value and im trying to get the "OR" clause between the duplicate fields

Comment: Perfect, @Damien_The_Unbeliever solution works properly with a simple modification: 
`SELECT TAG,MAX( CAST (Bool1 AS INT )) as Bool1, MAX( CAST (Bool2 as INT)) as Bool2,MAX( CAST( Bool3 as INT)) as Bool3
from Table group by TAG`

Comment: Updated. Thanks. It's annoying because in many places, `bit` is described as a *numeric* type, and so `MAX()` could easily be well defined.

Comment: Anyway, nice solution and nice re-cast to BIT.